# MSVC Remove esp, and JMC (CheckForDebugger) call generation for specific function

Tags: visual-c++, code-generation, disassembly

I have a function I want to bounce to shellcode. for ease of use in the future, i'd like to not have to separately compile it or induce strict compiler settings on projects that may use it.

I have 3 things i'd like to do

disable JMC _CheckForMyDebugger call generation

disable _Check_ESP call generation (done with __declspec(safebuffer))

disable function comdat linking/jmp function linking

All on a per function basis, any clues into what I can use to do this using MSVC?

Answer (score 0):

If you found this question, through hours of searching here's what I've figured out:

Declare functions with __declspec(safebuffers) and wrap them in the following pragma defines :

```
#pragma runtime_checks( "", off )
[function here]
#pragma runtime_checks( "", restore )
```

This removes the ESP checks

As for JMC and comdat linking, you must adjust the project settings. Unfortunately MSVC doesn't offer settings to adjust those on a per-function basis.